# next.js redirect on getServerSideProps throwing error about props

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am just trying to redirect from this page to another if my expression fails. I read the documentation, did exactly as they did, looked online did what they did and I get this every time.

```
Error: Additional keys were returned from `getServerSideProps`. Properties intended for your component must be nested under the `props` key, e.g.:

    return { props: { title: 'My Title', content: '...' } }

Keys that need to be moved: redirect.
Read more: https://err.sh/next.js/invalid-getstaticprops-value
This error happened while generating the page. Any console logs will be displayed in the terminal window.
```

And this is my code inside of the page

```
export async function getServerSideProps(req) {
  if(req){
    return {
      redirect: {
        permanent: false,
        destination: "/"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, you want to temporally redirect to the base URL all the time. If that's the case, it makes sense to have the logic defined in `next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  async redirects() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/your-page', // whatever your page is
        destination: '/',
        permanent: false,
      },
    ]
  },
}
```

***Reference***

https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/redirects

Comment: I tried it, didnt work. Im using 9.5 - going to try upgrading to 10

Comment: @noobCoder I forgot to ask the version. Yes, redirect on the `getServerSideProps` are introduced in Next.js 10. https://nextjs.org/blog/next-10#redirect-support